# Finding distance between every point in a matrix

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix, multidimensional-array

```
def create_zero_matrix(n,m):
    return [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]

def m_tight_print(m):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        line = ''
        for j in range(len(m[0])):
            line += str(m[i][j])
        print(line)


def pd_map(r,c,sites):
    blank = create_zero_matrix(r,c)
    for count, site in enumerate(sites):
        blank[site[0]][site[1]] = count #locating the shops
```

Hello, how do I calculate the distance of every point in my matrix from a specific point such as [1,3] (point 0) or [4,7] (point 1) or [7,2] (point 2) and change that particular value such that it shows the point that is closest to that particular coordinate?

```
>>> pprint(pizzaMap)
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'X', 1, 1]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'X', 1, 1, 1]
 ['X', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 'X', 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 'X', 1, 1]]
```

This above is the test case but I can only get this from my code.

````
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```.
I tried to use numpy.argwhere() but in the end I could not do it. What code must I use such that I am able to get my test case?
````

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework task.

Comment: Further, your task cannot be solved unless you specify what you mean with 'distance'. There are several distance measures, which one do you refer to?

Comment: Also, I think you are misusing the term 'matrix' here. Yes, you store it in a 2D array, but that does not make it a 'matrix' in the mathematical sense of matrix math.
What you are trying to accomplish here is called a 'Voronoi diagram'. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)